# JQuery .sortable() only works AFTER page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a case of a page containing a lot of JQuery, of which almost all of it works. All of it apart from:

```
private sortableOptions = {
    JSPA: this,
    delay: 50,
    group: "favourites",
    connectWith: ".sel-favourite-groups",
    vertical: false,
    itemSelector: "app-favourite",
    placeholder: "<li class='placeholder favourite list-group-item' style=''></li>",
    tolerance: 15,
    onDrop: this.sortDrop,
    onDragStart: this.sortDragStart
};


$list.sortable(this.sortableOptions);
```

This however does work if I refresh the page (press f5 etc).

When not working (on first page load) what I see is that list items are movable(you can click and drag them around), the event `onDragStart` fires, and the event `onDrop` fires. However while moving them no placeholder is displayed, and the other elements don't shift position. On drop the moving element just returns to its original location.

The relevant code in question in full is:

```
private render(): JQuery {
        let $page = this.getTemplate("home");

        let $list = $page.find("#home-favourites");
        $list.sortable(this.sortableOptions);

        try {
            for (let f = 0; f < this.user.UserSettings.favourites.sites.length; f++) {
                this.drawFavourite($list, this.user.UserSettings.favourites.sites[f]);
            }

            // and do the same for the groups
            for (let g = 0; g < this.user.UserSettings.favourites.groups.length; g++) {
                let group = this.user.UserSettings.favourites.groups[g];
                // add the header and list to the DOM
                let $list = this.drawFavouriteGroup(group);
                $list.sortable(this.sortableOptions);

                if (group.state == "minimised") {
                    let $li = $list.parent();
                    this.drawMinimisedFavouriteGroup($li, group.name);
                    $li.addClass("collapse");
                }

                for (let f = 0; f < group.sites.length; f++) {
                    this.drawFavourite($list, group.sites[f]);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (ex) {
            console.log("EXCEPTION:: Home.render(): ", ex);
        }

        return $page;
    }
```

From reviewing other similar issues (normally that JQuery things DON'T work after a refresh) I have already tried:

- Adding everything to the DOM then calling `.sortable()`
- Calling `.sortable('refresh')`
- Simplifying the code so the 'groups' above(multiple `<ul />`s aren't included

None of these made any difference - never works on first load, always works after page refresh

Also navigating away from the page, and back means the `.sortable()` doesn't work.

What I can't understand is how a refresh can make it work, shouldn't an initial page load when navigated to - with no cached content - be identical to hitting f5?

As I said at the start, there is A LOT of other jQuery on the page all of which works as expected.

Anyone got any idea what might be going on here?